# Bootstrap-vue doesn't load CSS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am writing a Vue.js app with Bootstrap 4 and I can't loaded though I followed the documentation.

Added to main.js

`Vue.use(BootstrapVue);`

Added to css file related to App.vue:

```
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```

Here is template:

```
<div class="main">
<div>

    <b-modal id="modal1" title="Something went wrong" v-if="!serverStatusOk">
        <p class="my-4">{{msg}}</p>
        <p class="my-4">{{statusCode}}</p>

    </b-modal>
</div>

<div>
    <b-tab title="Players" active>
        <br>Players data
    </b-tab>
    <b-tab title="Tournaments" active>
        <br>Tournament data
    </b-tab>
</div>
```

Result: no css rendered but in css file from dist dir I see Bootstrap
What am I missing? The project created by vue-cli 3.0-beta

Comment: Same thing with Vue 2.5 and Bootstrap-Vue 2.0.0. The CSS files do resolve, as changing the path raises a Not Found error during compilation. No style takes effect.

Answer (score 14):

Try importing the files using JavaScript.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

---

On closer inspection it looks like you're missing `<b-tabs>` 
 
also `<b-modal>` is controlled by `v-model`

```
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <b-modal id="modal1" title="Something went wrong" v-model="errorModal">
            <pre class="my-4">{{ msg }}</pre>
            <p class="my-4">{{ statusCode }}</p>
        </b-modal>
    </div>
    <!-- Make sure to wrap b-tab in b-tabs -->
    <b-tabs> 
        <b-tab title="Players" active>
                <br>Players data
        </b-tab>
        <b-tab title="Tournaments">
                <br>Tournament data
        </b-tab>
    </b-tabs>
</div>
```

That should fix the styling of the tabs.

Comment: should I import to component?

Comment: You'll want it in App.vue if that's your root component

Comment: still no luck. the same result

Comment: Can you share more of your code? I could have a look on github or https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: https://github.com/abondar24/SocialTournamentService/tree/master/admin_frontend but I havent commited yet latest changes with import

Comment: commited import to App.vue

Answer (score 12):

I came across this same issue, but luckily I found the cause: The loader is not loaded :)

1. Make sure you have both **vue-style-loader** and **css-loader** in `package.json`
2. Then in your webpack config, your **module.rules** should have this object:

   ```
   {
     test: /\.css/,
     use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader'] // BOTH are needed!
   }
   ```
3. And in your `App.vue`, under the `<script>` section, you should import:

   ```
   import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
   import "bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css";
   ```

No need to use `@` or relative `node_modules` paths or anything.

With these changes, it worked for me with Vue 2.5 and Bootstrap-Vue 2.0.0

---

**Update:**

Also, even though it feels a bit counter-intuitive, make sure you `use()` the Bootstrap-Vue package **BEFORE** you create the `new Vue()` in **main.js**. For example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

If you do it in reverse order, it works only partially. For example some block elements will not have styles applied.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import App from './App';
import router from './router';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App),
});

// Doing this after new Vue() will NOT work correctly:
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
```

Comment: I did exactly same as in first example , and im using vscode as editor but its clearly saying that 'BootstrapVue' is declared but cant read ?? in browser console got the error  [Show/hide message details.] ReferenceError: BootstrapVue is not defined

Comment: @ARUNMadathil: That sounds like the ``bootstrap-vue`` package did not install correctly. You could try running ``npm install bootstrap-vue --save`` again, and check that no errors appear during the install. You should get an entry in your project's ``package.json`` dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

For new people facing above issue. None of the above answers worked for me. My problem was with installed bootstrap version. npm installled lastest version `5.1.0` which does not work with bootstrap-vue. I had to downgrade bootstrap to `4.5.3` [(recommended version from website)](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs)

run following
`npm install bootstrap@4.5.3 --save`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Didn't think of this (after almost half an hour of debugging...) while helping a (junior) friend struggling adding BootstrapVue to his project!

Comment: Thank you, I was pulling my hair why only some elements were not being styles. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: the command in bootstrap-vue's getting started page is so wrong! `npm install vue bootstrap bootstrap-vue` when you do that it installs the latest version of bootstrap which is incompatible with bootstrap-vue...

Comment: Thanks! I had the same problem "the other way around", i.e. using `bootstrap-vue-next` with Bootstrap 4 instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

`bootstrap-vue` require specific version of `bootstrap` in order to work correctly. Below is the recommendation from the [Bootstrap-vue doc](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs) at the time of writing.

```
Vue.js v2.6 is required, v2.6.12 is recommended
Bootstrap v4.3.1 is required, v4.5.3 is recommended
Popper.js v1.16 is required for dropdowns (and components based on dropdown), tooltips, and popovers. v1.16.1 is recommended
PortalVue v2.1 is required by Toasts, v2.1.7 is recommended
jQuery is not required
```

Solution:
Please install with the version `yarn add bootstrap@4.5.3` or `npm -i bootstrap@4.5.3`

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a combination/variation of some of the other answers.

App.vue:

```
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'


// Install BootstrapVue
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
// Optionally install the BootstrapVue icon components plugin
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'



export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
```

Sources:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/ui-library-styles-not-loading-in-web-components/77858/2
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was working with vue-cli 4.3.1, and I was using this configuration by error.

If you remove this configuration then all work nice!

https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#css-modules

> If you want to drop the .module in the filenames, set css.requireModuleExtension to false in vue.config.js:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    requireModuleExtension: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Solution:

Import to App.vue:

```
'../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
'../../node_modules/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
```